# using a library (ocrodjvu) that used to be installable through pip but now isn't?

Tags: python-3.x, github, installation, pip, lib

I'd like to add a feature that was implemented in another project distributed under GPL3, which is based on the [ocrodjvu](https://github.com/jwilk-archive/ocrodjvu) library, which used to be installable through pip and is now not.
The library was transferred to python3.

I tried to install it through apt (from Linux Mint), which reported having no candidate for installation, and pip had returned 'no available version satisfying the requirements'. Installing the library from source (github link) isn't possible due to the absence of setup.py or .toml installation scripts, and the attempts to make it from Makefile has resulted in errors.

Is there a way to make use of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a fork supporting python3 and installation by setup.py:  https://github.com/FriedrichFroebel/ocrodjvu